# Div going beyond the background color

Tags: html, css, web-applications, stylesheet

What I want to do is that the background color will remain the same no matter how big the screen resolution is for the reader. I created a div where its height is set to auto.

```
.news-box{
margin-top:5%;
border-radius:6px;
background-color: #EEE;
border: 1px solid #EEE;
margin-left: 24%;
height:auto;
width:620px;
}
```

This how it looks like

[image]

And this my CSS rule for the whole html

I am using this body css rule. for my gradient

**CSS RULE FOR THE WHOLE PAGE**

```
html
{
  height:100%;
}
```

**THIS COMES BEFORE THE .news-box class**

```
body
{
background: rgb(125,126,125); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 39%, rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(39%,rgba(125,126,125,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(14,14,14,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 39%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 39%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 39%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 39%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

This how the page looks like without the Div

[image]

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Please share ur HTML Code too. You might have placed the div in a wrong location!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/Xj5EGi4y)***.....................................

Hey now used to `min height` `100%` in you `html and body` as like this

```
html, body{
min-height:100%;

}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/Xj5EGi4y)***